# Theme Inheritance

Tags: magento2, luma-theme, inheritance

I have installed Magento 2.1.7, and theme Luma.
I then created a custom theme to inherit from Luma.
I was wondering if the content (blocks and widgets) are also inherited from the parent theme. In my case it does not see to happen. Is it the correct behavior or I am missing something?
See the screenshots.

Thanks

[image: The Luma Theme Home Page]

[image: My new Home Page, inherited theme from Luma]

Answer (score 2):

Static blocks and widget are not showing in your custom theme because of luma theme blocks and widget are them specific define.

You can see below attached screen shot.

[image]

If you want to show all Luma theme static blocks and widget then you need to create it and assign to your theme.

Comment: Nice answer @S H Patel.

Answer (score 1):

because this content of luma theme show by widget. Widget only apply to specific theme design. So in your theme doesn't define any widget related to content block so it empty